# Deploying a Web Forms site in the subdirectory of another Web Forms site

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am attempting to deploy an MS ASP.NET Web Forms site in a subdirectory of a legacy site.  Let's say the root URL is `tld.com` and the subdirectory is `~/dir`.  (I know, not very original.)  The new site is an upgrade of the old; the old site works properly and must continue to work properly.  The namespace for the old project is `TLD` and for the new project is `TLD_V2`.

I have already found out that `tld.com/dir/web.config` cannot be a complete file, for it contains entries that conflict with `tld.com/web.config`.  For now I have removed `~/dir/web.config`.

I next discovered that my landing page `~/dir/Default.aspx` contained the directive `MasterPage="~/main.Master"`, pointing to the root directory, and that I had to change this to reflect the local directory:  `MasterPage="./main.Master"`.

Now the web server is reporting a parser error in main.Master:  `Could not load type 'TLD_V2.Main'.`  The directive line in ~/dir/main.Master is:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="main.Master.cs" Inherits="TLD_V2.Main" %>
```

I have verified that main.Master.designer.cs contains the matching namespace.  I have also attempted to change the CodeBehind to `./main.Master.cs`; this didn't change anything.

I'm at a loss for what to do next.

(Down the road, we're planning to rewrite this site using MS MVC.  But that's not an option right this moment.)

Comment: Have you tried, or is it, a **separate/its own application**?

Comment: It's supposed to be a separate application/site.  The two sites have separate databases, logins, etc.

Comment: Have you configured it to be so (a separate application, instead of a sub-directory in IIS Manager)? That way, has it's own web.config, application root, etc. (so things like the tilde slash points to the right app root)....

Comment: We use a web hosting service and I don't have direct access to IIS Manager.  I'll see what their control interface supports for setting up the new site as an application.

Comment: I don't see any option on the web host's interface for publishing an application as opposed to a site.  Maybe there's something in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: @EdSF: Would you please point me to an article that would show me how to publish `tld.com/new` as a separate application at that URL.  The URL is fixed by the customer's business needs.

Comment: Hmmm...does your host allow you to create [virtual directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx) through some admin interface they provide? - my bad, I should have been more specific about _virtual directory_ ...

Comment: Yes.  I presently have the virtual directory `TLD_V2` pointing to the physical directory (in the hosting space) `TLD/wwwroot/TLD_V2`.

Comment: Now that I've moved back to using a virtual directory, I no longer get the original issue.  The present issue is that every. single. ASPX. file comes up totally blank.

Answer (score 0):

We worked around the issue by making subdomains, e.g. `TLD_V2.TLD`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subdomain would work - that makes things completely separate (and works with DNS).

Going back to the original goal of creating a "directory" ...apologies, didn't have time to actually do a "scaffold" earlier. That said these are based on default scaffolding in Visual Studio for Web Forms (2 separate Visual Studio WebForms web apps):

- In IIS Manager (or some host provided UI - **if possible/available**), create a *New Application* within your existing "parent":

[image: add new IIS application]

- You will end up with an IIS structure that looks like this. Note that icon with the "globe" - this represents an *application* (with it's own `web.config` etc.):

[image: IIS folder structure]

- The folllowing screen shots show "sub directory navigation" between applications (the arrows point to their respective *master pages* content):

  - **Main** app Home [image: Main app home]
  - **Sub** app Home [image: Sub app home]
  - **Main** app internal nav (Main App Home -> about page) [image: Main app nav]
  - **Sub** app internal nav (Sub App Home -> about page) [image: SubApp nav]

Hope this helps....